# randomly generating a switch case in java

Tags: java, switch-statement

Hello I am trying to generate a random case to be used to display a string.
So far the code below will only output case 2. For example, if the randomNum was 1, I would like it to print out what is in case 1, and if the randomNum was 2, I would like it to print out what is in case 2. Please let me know if this is possible or not, and show me how I can correct my code if it is possible. Thank you for your help!

```
  String Aries = "";
  Random number = new Random();
  int i = 0;
  int randomNum = number.nextInt(2) + 1;

  switch(randomNum)
  {
    case 1:
      Aries = "On April 2...";
    case 2:
      Aries = "In 2018...";
  }
  System.out.println(Aries);
```

Comment: You need a `break` in the cases. [The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: You can simply use a `List` containing your strings, rather than a switch.

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions : attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in lowerCase (Aries => aries)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `break` at the end of each `case` statement. If you don't add this `break` and enter in one `case`, every following cases will be executed like shown in this snippet :

```
int i = 2;

switch(i) {
  case 1 :
    System.out.println("case 1");
    // add "break;" here
  case 2:
    System.out.println("case 2");
    // add "break;" here
  case 3:
    System.out.println("case 3");
    /* Optionally but strongly recommended, 
     * you shall also add a "break;" here
     * so that there is no surprise if you add a case.
     */
}
```

Output :

```
case 2
case 3
```

Also, you can simplify the code by replacing the switch/case with a String array:

```
String[] strings = new String[]{"case 1", "case 2", "case 3"};
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(strings.length);
System.out.println(strings[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop de case you need to use a break sentence, like this...

```
    Random number = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    int randomNum = number.nextInt(2) + 1;
    String aries;

    switch(randomNum){
        case 1:
            aries = "On April 2...";
            break; //<- stop the switch
        case 2:
            aries = "In 2018...";
            break; //<- stop the switch
    }

    System.out.println(aries);
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

`switch` `case` statements fall-through by default. Minimal change, add `break` to at least `case 1` (although adding it to `case 2` would also be advisible). Like,

```
String Aries = "";
Random number = new Random();
int randomNum = number.nextInt(2) + 1;
switch (randomNum) {
case 1:
    Aries = "On April 2...";
    break;
case 2:
    Aries = "In 2018...";
    break;
}
System.out.println(Aries);
```

However, you only have two cases - so a `boolean` and `if-else` would be shorter (and more readable). Also, you don't seem to need `Aries` except for printing. So I would eliminate it. Like,

```
Random number = new Random();
if (number.nextBoolean()) {
    System.out.println("On April 2...");
} else {
    System.out.println("In 2018...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add break like these and it will work

```
import java.util.*;
 public class aaaaa {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   String Aries = "";
     Random number = new Random();
     int i = 0;
     int randomNum = number.nextInt(2) + 1;

     switch(randomNum)
     {
       case 1:
         Aries = "On April 2...";
         break;
       case 2:
         Aries = "In 2018...";
         break;
     }
System.out.println(Aries );

}
```

}

Answer (score -3):

I'd  create a random number between a range.
    Int ran0 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 2 + 1);

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's problem, which is not including a `break` statement in every case.

Comment: nope, it's only because there is no break